# Как вывести файлы каталога и подкаталога на php?

Tags: php, html

Есть некая папка в ней папки, а в папках файлы.
Как вывести файлы каталога и подкаталога на php, с ссылками на файлы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    $dir = "/some_dir/";   //задаём имя директории
    if(is_dir($dir)) {   //проверяем наличие директории
         echo $dir.' - директория существует;<br>'; 
         $files = scandir($dir);    //сканируем (получаем массив файлов)
         array_shift($files); // удаляем из массива '.'
         array_shift($files); // удаляем из массива '..'
         for($i=0; $i<sizeof($files); $i++) echo '-файл: <a href="'.$dir.$files[$i].'" title="открыть/скачать файл или страницу">'.$files[$i].'</a>;<br>';  //выводим все файлы
    } 
    else echo $dir.' -такой директории нет;<br>';
?>
Не судите строго если чтото не так!
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо LordySL. После долгих поисков для вывода на локальном сервере, именно это решение работает для вывода файлов и ссылок на них. Только вывод изменил для открытия файлов.

```
$dir = "C:/OpenServer/domains/site01.2/cls/";   //задаём имя директории
if(is_dir($dir)) {   //проверяем наличие директории
     echo $dir.' - директория существует;<br>'; 
     $files = scandir($dir);    //сканируем (получаем массив файлов)
     array_shift($files); // удаляем из массива '.'
     array_shift($files); // удаляем из массива '..'

     //for($i=0; $i<sizeof($files); $i++) echo '-файл: <a href="'.$dir.$files[$i].'" title="открыть/скачать файл или страницу">'.$files[$i].'</a>;<br>';  

     for($i=0; $i<sizeof($files); $i++) echo '-файл: <a href="http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/cls/".$files[$i].'" title="открыть/скачать файл или страницу">'.$files[$i].'</a>;<br>';  //выводим все файлы
} 
else echo $dir.' -такой директории нет;<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/article";   //задаём имя директории
    if(is_dir($dir)) {   //проверяем наличие директории
         //echo $dir.' - директория существует;<br>'; 
         $files = scandir($dir);    //сканируем (получаем массив файлов)
         array_shift($files); // удаляем из массива '.'
         array_shift($files); // удаляем из массива '..'
         //for($i=0; $i<sizeof($files); $i++) echo '<a href="'.$dir.$files[$i].'" title="открыть/скачать файл или страницу">'.$files[$i].'</a><br>';  //выводим все файлы
      for($i=0; $i<sizeof($files); $i++) echo '<a href="http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/article/".$files[$i].'" title="открыть/скачать файл или страницу">'.$files[$i].'</a>';  //выводим все файлы
   } 
    else echo $dir.' -такой директории нет;<br>';


?>
```